# Angular routerLink does nothing and redirect to the home page

Tags: angular, routes

When I click on the routerLink nothing happens and if I try open the link (copying to the adress bar) it redirects me to `http://localhost:4200`.

**book.component.html**

```
    <h2>Books</h2>
<ul class="books">
    <li *ngFor="let book of books">
        <a routerLink="/detail/{{book.key}}">
            {{book.key}} {{book.title}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**{{book.key}} equals something like this: /works/OL27448W**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:key', component: BookDetailComponent }
];
```

Comment: Most likely this route is going to fail because you have an additional `/` symbol in your book key. The actual route Angular would try to look for would then be `detail/works/:key`

Comment: Thanks, changing the root to detail/works/:key solved the problem. But I think I am going to split the key so it won't contain / symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.

**First**: Read @Mikkel Christensen comment.

**Second**: This is also based on what Christensen wrote about the additional `/` symbol. I wrote a custom pipe based on this article: https://dev.to/kenan7/creating-split-custom-pipe-in-angular-3n8f. And split my key so it doesn't contain the symbol. /works/OL27448W -> OL27448W I can do this because the /works/ part always the same.
You can see it below.

**books.component.html**

```
<h2>Books</h2>
<ul class="books">
    <li *ngFor="let book of books">
        <a routerLink="/detail/{{book.key | split: '/' : 2}}">
            {{book.key}} {{book.title}}
        </a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

**split.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'split'
})
export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(text: string, by: string, index: number = 1) {
    let arr = text.split(by); // split text by "by" parameter
    return arr[index] // after splitting to array return wanted index
  }
}
```

**routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:key', component: BookDetailComponent }
];
```